# sprite kit - objective c: slow fps when I create a lot nodes

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I wanted to create a space background so I make a for loop to create the stars. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
SKShapeNode *star= [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:Path.CGPath];
    star.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    star.physicsBody = nil;
    int xposition = arc4random()%960;
    int yposition = arc4random()%640;
    star.position = CGPointMake(xposition, yposition);
    float size = (arc4random()%3 + 1)/10.0;
    star.xScale = size;
    star.yScale = size;
    star.alpha = (arc4random()%10 + 1 )/ 10.0;
    star.zPosition = -2;
     [self addChild:star];
}
```

But it takes a lot from my cpu. when the code is activated the cpu at top 78%.(I check the code in the iPhone simulator);

[image]

Somebody know how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: @Droppy  no. the application in only the code that I sent

Comment: Don't worry so much about CPU usage. What is more important is your FPS staying in the 55 to 60 range. Secondly, the simulator is useless for real world stats. Use an actual device for accurate feedback.

Comment: @sangony the fps is 15 when this code is working. and I don't have Apple developer so i can't text it on a real device

Comment: Without a real device you will never be able to test properly.

Comment: @100tomer Using a SKShapeNode like this will end up in 100 draw calls which can pretty much affect on performance in a bad way. Enable debug labels in your view controller (skView.showsDrawCount = YES) and you'll see everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your physics bodies continue to calculate even when off of the screen. You will need to remove them once they go out of the frame, otherwise everything will slow to a crawl. (And to echo what others have stated you will eventually need a real device).

From this document: [Jumping Into Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW14)

You can implement the "Did Simulate Physics" method to get rid of the stars that fell from the bottom of the screen like so:

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"star" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.y < 0)
        [node removeFromParent];
}];
}
```

Note that you will first need to set the name of your star shapes by using the name property like so:

```
star.name = "star"
```

Comment: the stars not falling down so this code can't help me,

Comment: My mistake I thought you were using the stars as a scrolling background. 

It's definitely just because you're running it in the simulator then. I wouldn't worry much about it.